# How to keep iOS app alive while in background, longer than 10 minutes?

Tags: ios, swift

I found this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5247-core-location-tutorial-for-ios-tracking-visited-locations (you can download the sample project and play with it.) which will track you by giving you long/lat, even if the app is closed or backgrounded, it will continue to give you the lat/long. However, if the app is backgrounded, and I leave the phone alone for about 10 minutes, the app seems to go into some kind of "suspend" state, in which when I pick it up again, the app no longer track you (no lat/long) until you bring the app to the foreground(you can now see the UI), then it will resume tracking. But I want this app to continue tracking, while in the background indefinitely. I don't want it to go into a suspend mode.

For testing purposes, I made the code:

```
   locationManager.distanceFilter = 3 // give me lat/long every 3 meters
```

I tried a lot of things to get this to work, for example, I created a recursive function that will run indefinitely, just to keep the app alive. But it did not work

Comment: are you saying my request is not possible ?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background (you'll also want to read the rest of the documentation on location services) There is no generic way to remain running in the background indefinitely, but for the specific case of location tracking (and certain other use cases), there are tools. Looking over the tutorial, it seem to skip over setting the Background Modes, which is likely why you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When application enters the "Background" state - you code still running, but after several minutes app move to "Suspended" state and system can kill application for free memory, in this state you code doesn't work

[image: plan]